# Image with area where other images are added in random order

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, image-processing

I have a background image with object of some shape (example below). I would like to add new images - layers (simple div with position:absolute - left/top) to this image and only on the shape where I want.

[image: first sample]

And then with PHP code added images (for example 10, 50,..) to only this shape and no other place:

[image: second example]

Is this possible to do on any simple way with PHP/JS/jquery/...? I just need to pass how many items and that many images is added to that area...

Comment: PHP runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. I don't think you understand what you're really asking for here. Please be more specific.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it's done, it can be done in client or server side. Both will be OK. As written, I don't need layers to be burned on the picture, but added as divs with absolute position. As much as I can see it can only be done by getting valid X/Y positions of area, but that's the biggest problem to get.

Is there maybe and tool where I could upload image and then draw a shape and the script calculates all X/Y values inside selected area? That would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete rewrite of my answer.

Given a random picture, fit many *smaller* pictures only where some `color` is matched:

I decided to go with a crab as a starting pictures, because crabs are cool:

[image: Crab]

I only want to add red dots where there is blue in the picture

[image: Red dots]

To do this, I will split my answer in 3 sections:

**HTML**

I start with a very simple HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Crab Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Dots on the crab example</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="crabSection">
            <img src="crab.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This gives us a starting point for rendering our dotted crab!

**PHP**

Now, in PHP, I open both my `crab.png` and my `dot.png` to analyze their content, and locate random positions where the `dot.png` can fit in an `all blue` section. Right after the `<img src="crab.png">`, I inserted the following:

```
<?php
        $crab = imagecreatefrompng("crab.png");
        $dot = imagecreatefrompng("dot.png");

        $numDesiredDots = 10;
        $numCreatedDots = 0;

        $crabWidth = imagesx($crab);
        $crabHeight = imagesy($crab);

        $dotWidth = imagesx($dot);
        $dotHeight = imagesy($dot);

        $spawnableWidth = $crabWidth - $dotWidth;
        $spawnableHeight = $crabHeight - $dotHeight;

        srand(time());

        $testingForDotSubpart = imagecreatetruecolor($dotWidth, $dotHeight);

        $validCoordinates = array();
        $invalidCoordinates = array();

        $colorWereLookingFor = 0xFF; // ARGB - our crab is blue
```

Here, a few details:

- `$numDesiredDots` is hardcoded to 10, but it could easily be a parameter!
- `$spawnableWidth` and `$spawnableHeight` represent the greatest coordinate a `dot` can be placed in without going out of the picture
- `srand(time());` is simply used to have a different random everytime
- `$testingForDotSubpart` is a small image I will be using to test a given coordinate to see if it only contains pixels of the right color
- `$colorWereLookingFor` is set to `blue` now, because my crab is blue, if you wanted `red`, it should be something like `0xFF0000`. For this example I used the same PNG for the HTML and the image processing, but you could easily just create a mask for the image processing and have a full color image for the HTML.

Now, we need to create valid coordinates for each dot, which is done with the following php:

```
        while($numCreatedDots < $numDesiredDots)
        {
            $randomX = rand() % $spawnableWidth;
            $randomY = rand() % $spawnableHeight;

            imagecopy($testingForDotSubpart, $crab, 0, 0, $randomX, $randomY, $dotWidth, $dotHeight);
            $valid = true;
            for($x = 0; $x < $dotWidth; $x++)
            {
                for($y = 0; $y < $dotHeight; $y++)
                {
                    if(imagecolorat($testingForDotSubpart, $x, $y) != $colorWereLookingFor)
                    {
                        $valid = false;
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($valid)
            {
                array_push($validCoordinates, array('x' => $randomX, 'y' => $randomY));
                $numCreatedDots++;
            }
            else
            {
                // you can get rid of this else, it's just to show you how many fails there are
                array_push($invalidCoordinates, array('x' => $randomX, 'y' => $randomY));
            }
        }
```

Again, some explanation:

- We iterate as long as we haven't created all the dots we want, for a very complex image, this might take too much time, you could add a maximum number of tries
- We start by creating a random `X,Y` coordinate
- We copy the small window where the dot could end up
- We test all the pixels inside this window to make sure they are of the right color
- If the window is valid, we add the coordinates to an array
- For debugging purposes, I added an `$invalidCoordinates` array to show how many tries failed - the more complex the picture, the more fails there will be

Now that we have computed all our positions, we need to clean up the resources:

```
        imagedestroy($testingForDotSubpart);
        imagedestroy($dot);
        imagedestroy($crab);
```

Finally, I added some debug output that you can get rid of, but we need to output the dots on the crab! To show you that each dot is unique, I attached a `JavaScript` `alert` that shows the dot index:

```
        echo "<p>Valid Coords: <br>";

        foreach($validCoordinates as $coord)
        {
            echo "X: " . $coord['x'] . " Y: " . $coord['y'] . "<br>\n";
        }

        echo "<br>Invalid Coords " . count($invalidCoordinates) . "</p>\n";

        // Now add the dots on the crab!
        for($i = 0; $i < count($validCoordinates); $i++)
        {
            $coord = $validCoordinates[$i];
            echo "<div class='dot' style='left:".$coord['x'].";top:".$coord['y'].";'><a href='javascript:alert(".$i.");'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>\n";
        }        
?>
```

Here, I am using the `style` `left` and `top` to give precise pixel positioning to the dots. To have them match precisely with the parent picture, we need to use `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` as described in the next section.

**CSS**

As you can see, I'm using a class for the `div`, this is to take advantage of the `relative positioning`. I added at the top of the file, right after the title, the following

```
        #crabSection { position:relative; }
        .dot { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; position:absolute; }
```

**Result**

Here's a run of the given script... you could easily save the HTML generated so you don't have to recompute positions everytime:

[image: Browser]

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: here's the full code, if you need it: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2HRrq7PC)

**Edit 2**: note that there is no overlap checking, you might want to check that the rectangle defined by `$randomX`, `$randomY`, `$randomX + $dotWidth` and `$randomY + $dotHeight` doesn't overlap an existing rectangle from the coordinates in `$validCoordinates`.

**Edit 3**: Once generated you can simply open the source of the page, and copy the `div` to your `HTML` so it's not regenerated everytime.

```
<div class='dot' style='left:100;top:105;'><a href='javascript:alert(0);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:150;top:151;'><a href='javascript:alert(1);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:128;top:73;'><a href='javascript:alert(2);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:144;top:93;'><a href='javascript:alert(3);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:164;top:91;'><a href='javascript:alert(4);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:108;top:107;'><a href='javascript:alert(5);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:22;top:101;'><a href='javascript:alert(6);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:54;top:151;'><a href='javascript:alert(7);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:32;top:121;'><a href='javascript:alert(8);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
<div class='dot' style='left:142;top:87;'><a href='javascript:alert(9);'><img src='dot.png'></a></div>
```

Also, as long as the color mask described by the `$crab` picture opened in PHP, you can change the `img src` to something else if you wanted a colorful crab. I added a `crabc.png` file which is now used by my `img`, but it still has the same outline as the `crab.png` file:

[image: Colored Crab]

Which gives this final look:

[image: Browser with Color]

Comment: As written I would like to add divs with relative positions, but the problem is getting X/Y positions which are valid. Is there maybe and tool where I could upload image and then draw a shape and the script calculates all X/Y values inside selected area? That would be very useful. Something like http://www.mobilefish.com/services/record_mouse_coordinates/record_mouse_coordinates.php but this only shows selected point positions not all positions in selected area...

Comment: I'm writing something for you which might be what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry it took quite some time to write :)

Comment: It looks great, but this now checks for good/bad area every reload, is there any way to simply check each pixel (X/Y position) and return array/string which can be saved and just added to code, so next time all this calculations won't need to be done anymore and it will use only random position of valid coordinates? Because this is now does real time checking on blue color, what about if I have random colors back or maybe even none at all - in that case I will only need coordinates for that image (and before usage I'll create shape blue color and get the coordinates). Do you know what I mean?

Comment: That's why I added `you could easily save the HTML generated so you don't have to recompute positions everytime`, just open the source of a run where you like the positioning of your items and save the `div` that were generated :) Also, you can change the image that's displayed as long as it matches the `mask` describing where to put the dots

Comment: Is there any way to modify the code to check every pixel 1:1,1:2,1:3,... and return valid positions in array? Because in my code I will have dynamic number of shown points and I'm not sure how to display X dots if I just have a list of divs from source (unless if I create lots of if sentences).

Comment: I managed to modify the code (it only needs a few lines modified) and now the script checks all pixels. I'll now try it on my sample and I hope it works out. This is amazing solution, thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to help! If you need an update on the code, just let me know

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure it's possible to add them to fit a shape unless that shape is created in svg.

You could have a div with an image in it which is an inverted arrow i.e. the image is white with the arrow cut out and a bgcolor on the div.

Then you could add the dots to the same div and just set their z-index to lower than the arrow image.

Then the dots will only appear in the arrow, only problem is some might be added but not be visible (only a problem if you need the user to interact with them).

What exactly do you want to do with the dots?

Comment: Yes, the dots have to be visible and in specific area, they will have link on them.

Comment: Hmm in which case I would have a look to see if you could do something with SVG, either that or divide the shape into rows and columns that way you can set a max/min left/top. 

I can;t think of another way of doing it. I would definitely use jQuery tho.

Comment: Is there maybe and tool where I could upload image and then draw a shape and the script calculates all X/Y values inside selected area? That would be very useful.

Comment: I don't know of one, perhaps have a look at some of the other folk's suggestions.